# Excel - Transpose data from multiple rows to single column with matched value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, pivot, powerquery

Ok, so I have some data that I want to convert from multiple rows to multiple columns.

My input data looks loosely like this -

```
+----------+----------------+-----------------+
|   SKU    | Attribute Name | Attribute Value |
+----------+----------------+-----------------+
| Product1 | Colour         | Black           |
| Product1 | Size           | Large           |
| Product1 | Height         | 20cm            |
| Product1 | Width          | 40cm            |
| Product2 | Colour         | Red             |
| Product2 | Width          | 30cm            |
| Product2 | Size           | Large           |
| Product3 | Height         | 25cm            |
| Product3 | Width          | 30cm            |
| Product3 | Length         | 90cm            |
| Product3 | Weight         | 5kg             |
| Product3 | Size           | Large           |
| Product3 | Colour         | Blue            |
+----------+----------------+-----------------+
```

What I want to achieve is an output like this -

```
+----------+--------+--------+--------+-------+--------+-------+
|   SKU    | Colour | Height | Length | Size  | Weight | Width |
+----------+--------+--------+--------+-------+--------+-------+
| Product1 | Black  | 20cm   |        | Large |        | 40cm  |
| Product2 | Red    |        |        | Large |        | 30cm  |
| Product3 | Blue   | 25cm   | 90cm   | Large | 5kg    | 30cm  |
+----------+--------+--------+--------+-------+--------+-------+
```

I've tried Pivot tables, but you can only return numeric values, rather than the text values I'm looking for.

I know I could probably achieve it using a number of step looking up values and filling them, but I feel like there should be a more simplistic way to achieve this. Maybe it's something better achieved in database rather than a spreadsheet.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to load this data into Access?  There is a fairly straightforward canonical query which can be used to generate the output you want in SQL.  Also, I think this can be done with pivot tables, I just don't know how.

Comment: If you have Excel 2010 /2013, you can use `Power Query` (a free MS add-in) or, in 2016 `Data-->Get & Transform` to "Pivot" on the `Attribute Name` column and choose `Do not aggregate` for the values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in ̶5̶ ̶s̶t̶e̶p̶s̶   4 steps with Powerquery. This is in-built for 2016 and a free add-in from Microsoft from 2013 on wards ( or 2010 Professional Plus with Software Assurance). See info https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=39379

The advantage is you can easily add rows to the source and simply refresh the query.

1) You select any cell in the range, then in 2016 Get & Transform tab, earlier version use the Powerquery tab, select data from table. A window will pop up with your range of data in:

[image: Step 1]

2) Transform > Pivot column >  Attribute Name column for Attribute Value  in Values Column (used advanced options to select "Don't aggregate")

[image: Pivot]

3) Drag columns around to desired arrangement

[image: Column order]

4) Home > Close and load to sheet

Here is a version without the column re-ordering

[image]

Edit:

Thanks to @Ron Rosenfeld for reminding me that truly *null* values don't need replacing with blanks as they will appear as blanks when written to the sheet.

So this step was removed:

4) Highlight columns to replace nulls in and go to transform > replace values > and

Value to Find: null

Replace With:

[image: Find and replace nulls]

Comment: I've found, in 2016, that the *null* is truly null. When I close out the query, the worksheet has empty cells in those spots.

Comment: That is the idea isn't it? Apologies, can't help but feel I am missing something here :-(

Comment: I think you can omit your step above of replacing *null* with nothing

Comment: Doh! Thanks I get it now.

Comment: @QHarr you're a lifesaver! Thanks so much for your help. I knew there must be a solution for this. Initially I was a bit lost as I couldn't find that option, but looks like it's not included in the Mac version, so switched over to my PC and found it there. Amazing stuff. Thanks again!

Comment: No worries. PowerQuery can be very nifty especially for file operations.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using a helper column and then match it using index + match. Not as simple as you thought, but does work.

1) Add helper column to your data (call it 'Helper'). `=concat(SKU,'Attribute Name')`

2) Use a pivot to get a unique list of SKUs in the rows so that it's easy to update once the data changes. (I'm assuming this is in column A and values start at row 4).

3) Use another pivot to get a unique list of Attributes in the columns next to the other pivot. Then you have the structure of your results. (I'm assuming the first value is in B3).

4) Index match the values of the table `=index('Attribute Value', match(concat($A4,B$3),'Helper',0))`

Note though that this only works when each combination of SKU and Attribute is unique.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that the data is in columns **A** through **C**:

```
Sub croupier()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long, vA As String, vB As String, vC As String
    Dim rw As Long, cl As Long

'                   setup column headers

    Columns(2).SpecialCells(2).Offset(1).Copy Range("D1")
    Columns(4).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    Columns(4).SpecialCells(2).Copy
    Range("E1").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
    Columns(4).SpecialCells(2).Clear

'                   setup row headers

    Columns(1).SpecialCells(2).Copy Range("D1")
    Columns(4).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes

'                    deal the data

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To N
        vA = Cells(i, 1)
        vB = Cells(i, 2)
        vC = Cells(i, 3)
        cl = Rows(1).Find(what:=vB, after:=Range("A1")).Column
        rw = Columns(4).Find(what:=vA, after:=Range("D1")).Row
        Cells(rw, cl) = vC
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]